# Unregister, Modify & Re-register ActiveX not updating Propertys

Tags: c#, com, activex

I Unregistered an ActiveX control I would like to develop with the following Regasm Command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /u     
"C:\Users\callu\OneDrive\BiologinAX5\BiologinAX5\bin\Debug\BiologinAX5.dll" /tlb
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /u 
"C:\Users\callu\OneDrive\BiologinAX5\BiologinAX5\bin\Debug\BiologinAX5.dll" /tlb
```

I then renamed one of my propertys from "WellColorMePurple" to "BtnBgColor", Cleaned the Project and then Built the project by changing the code as per below:

**Old**

```
    [DispId(5)]
    int WellColorMePurple { get; set; }
```

**New**

```
    [DispId(5)]
    int BtnBgColor { get; set; }
```

I then Reregistered using the Regasm commands below but in Excel it still shows me the old Property name
and no matter what I try it still shows the old name:

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks Callum

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe 
"C:\Users\callu\OneDrive\BiologinAX5\BiologinAX5\bin\Debug\BiologinAX5.dll" /codebase /tlb

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe 
"C:\Users\callu\OneDrive\BiologinAX5\BiologinAX5\bin\Debug\BiologinAX5.dll" /codebase /tlb
```

Comment: How does Excel reference the activex? Is it using the new tlb? or something else?

Comment: Hi Simon And thanks for responding. I add it in Excel using the Developer Tab and then Insert > More Controls. When I look in VBA references afterwards the tlb file is checked. I check using a new unsaved workbook everytime and then save inbetween my ActiveX modifications.

Comment: Have you checked the tlb manually (using OleView tool in the Windows SDK for example)?

Comment: Hi Simon, I hadn't. I just installed the SDK and am having a look just now. Thanks Callum

Comment: I have just checked using the OleViewer and the propertys have the correct name so this must be an Excel issue. Thanks for putting me on the right path. Cheers